# Order of execution: First file system, then array vs. first array, then file system

Tags: filesystems, mdadm, raid1, formatting, mkfs

Suppose I have two HDDs, same manufacturer, same model, same attributes (volume, speed, cache, ...). Both are equally partitioned. I want to have a level one array of two disks with one ext4 partition. Tool of choice: `mdadm`.

Which one is better?

**a)** Format each disk partition and then create the array.

**b)** Create the array and then format the array.

Is there a difference at all?

Comment: Duplicate: I've considered other already solved questions, however they relate to partitioning, performance, growth. I'm simply not confident what to do first, a) or b).

Comment: A: there's no "format partition", I guess you mean "make filesystem".  B: when you create the array you get a new block device and overwrite the physical devices, deleting any filesystem you've already created there, so your "a" option makes no sense.

Comment: Okay. That answers my question. After having read your comment, I did successfully create an array as described in b). *new block device* nails it. I simply didn't look at it in this way. If you'd post your comment as an answer, I could honor your effort by accepting it. Currently, I cannot even upvote your comment.